# Can I use regression with one independent variable?

Tags: regression, logistic, repeated-measures

I have a question regarding the right choice of statistical test for my data. 
My data is as follows:

[image: Variables of interest]

I want to assess the predictive power of the CognitiveScore regarding PerformanceHigh (yes or no, 1 or o resp) for every AgeCohort. However, due to how my data looks, there are repeated measures as you can see.

What is the best choice of statistical analysis? I thought of logistic binomial regression, or repeated measures logistic binomial regression, but is that even the right test? And if it is, can I perform it with only 1 IV?

Comment: You could probably perform repeated measures logistic regression.  If you were interested in making individual level predictions, you should probably choose a generalized linear mixed effects model using the binomial family.  Alternatively if you were interested in population-level analyses, you could consider generalized estimating equations, also with a binomial family.

Comment: Thank you! I'm interested to see in which agecohort the predicitive power of the CognitiveScore is highest, if that makes sense (see below). However, I do have repeated measures of subjects over time and most pp do not appear in all cohorts. What is the advice you would give me?

Answer (score 0):

Binomial logistic regression is what you are looking for. There is no problem in having only one variable (indeed, it's great as you will be able to draw a beautiful curve representing probability of high performance versus CognitiveScore)

I don't know about the specifics of your particular problem, but you may want to transform AgeCohort into a number and include it as a second regressor

Comment: Thank you for your help! My particular problem is that CognitiveScore is measured multiple times for each participant, i.e. in different AgeCohorts. So pp 1 is for example in AgeCohort 13-14, 14-15 and 15-16. My question really is: from what AgeCohort on is CognitiveScore the best predictor for PerformanceHigh (1/0)? In other words, which AgeCohort's CognitiveScore is the best predictor for PerformanceHigh ('measured' a couple of years later)?

To that end: do I have to account for the fact that there are repeated measures, or for the fact that not every pp is measured in every AgeCohort?

Comment: Well, if observations are not independent, then you may want to work on PerformanceHigh's evolution over time, rather than its actual value. But that's up to the specifics of your study

Comment: Thanks again for the fast comment. I'm interested to see from what age (i.e. in which agecohort) predictive power of the CognitiveScore is highest, really. Is that possible?